# Joining an column with conditions to JPA entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables:

```
person:
- person_id
- name

meeting:
- meeting_id
- person_id
- date
```

One person can have many meetings. My JPA entity for person looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@Getter
public class Person {

  @Id
  private Integer personId;

  private String name;

  @Formula("(SELECT m.date FROM meeting m WHERE ROWNUM <= 1 AND m.person_id = person_id ORDER BY m.date DESC)")
  private Date lastMeetingDate;
```

The problem is: **How to include last meeting date** into `Person` object. Code above generates ORA-00936 error (I'm using Oracle database).

SQL geneated by `findPersonById()`:

```
select person0_.person_id as person_id1_10, person0_.name as name2_10, (SELECT m.date FROM meeting m WHERE ROWNUM <= 1 AND m.person_id = person0_.person_id ORDER BY m.date DESC) as formula0_ form person person0_ where person0_.person_id=?
```

Comment: What is ORA-00936?

Comment: turn on sql logging in hibernate and post the generated output

Comment: @maciej-kowalski sql added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try:

`SELECT max(m.date) FROM meeting m WHERE m.person_id = person_id`